# Complete removal of apache2 under linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, unix, lamp

I have problem with removing apache2 under ubuntu. What I tried is:

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

unfortunatelly after any of upper commands, there are still files:

```
sudo find / -name "apache2"
/var/log/apache2
/var/lib/update-rc.d/apache2
/var/cache/apache2
/usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/examples/apache2
/usr/share/apache2
/usr/lib/apache2
/usr/lib/apache2/mpm-event/apache2
/usr/lib/apache2/mpm-itk/apache2
/usr/lib/apache2/mpm-worker/apache2
/usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2
/usr/sbin/apache2
/run/apache2
/run/lock/apache2
/etc/init.d/apache2
/etc/apache2
/etc/cron.daily/apache2
/etc/default/apache2
/etc/logrotate.d/apache2
```

When i run `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start`

```
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                            apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

After typing localhost in browser it responds with:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Could this files disturb new apache server installation? I've checked them all but nothing interresting found.

**EDIT:**
Upper output is after removal of the server. After removal of all files from `sudo find / -name "apache2"` I did install again `sudo apt-get install apache2`. `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2` outputs with:

```
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                            Segmentation fault
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

But error.log and access.log are empty.

Apache install:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-worker apache2-utils apache2.2-common
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec apache2-suexec-custom
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-worker apache2-utils apache2.2-common
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/321 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,240 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Is it normal that it asks only for `1,240 kB` space ?

Comment: Was apache2 removed when you fired the commands what output did you see

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First stop apache:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

Then, remove apache2 packages and dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

If you manually modified or installed stuff, apt might not remove it. Check what's left:

```
whereis apache2
```

Have a look whats inside these directories, and if you're confident you want to trash it, manually remove the directories as below:

```
sudo rm -Rf /etc/apache2 /usr/lib/apache2 /usr/include/apache2
```

Comment: Just wanted to open this thread to configure this apache properly with installation. But ok, I will start new thread because that will be other question.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Ujx.png)
**See the image of the error here**

***Remove apache2 from the Ubuntu***

To remove totally from your **localhost**

1st check the current status using

```
service apache2 status
```

if it's **active (running)**
write next

```
sudo apt remove apache2*
```

Say yes using **y**

And have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu, these commands will completely remove Apache2, all its configs, logs and www files.

***Warning**: `sudo rm -rf /var/www/html` will delete all files in your `/var/www/html` directory, make sure you don't have anything important there!!!*

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo apt purge apache2
sudo apt purge apache2-utils
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apache2
sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2
sudo rm -rf /var/www/html
sudo rm -rf /var/log/apache2
```